# How to handle questions getting buried?

Tags: discussion

While not all of my questions are the best, I often find they stay at very low views for longer periods with neither up votes nor down votes and after a while they simply get buried with no chance of every being found due to the way questions are arranged. Is there any way individuals can increase chances of their question being spotted by a possible answerer beyond accurate title and tags or anything they can do once it is buried and is there anything we can do as community to avoid questions getting buried? Note: I am aware of bounties, I'm looking for other possible solutions.

Comment: Without having gone through your profile to see what questions you are referring to (i.e., to see if it's too localized), but edits will bring things to the front page.

Comment: Note that you are trying to excel at what is essentially a zero-sum game. There is only so much attention to be given by the finite number of users here, so if you attract more attention, others will lose it. So while we might be able to help you in particular, the broader problem of questions being buried is more difficult to solve.

Answer (score 5):

On reviewing your questions I recall seeing some of them, finding the titles intriguing enough to warrant a quick read of the question and then moving on without leaving a comment of answer.

I think that you have moved beyond the mindset of most beginners (and congratulations), but haven't fully internalized the lessons of introductory coursework yet (no surprise there, it takes a while). That makes your text read like it was written by a physicist, but means your questions are not particularly interesting to me. At the same time, the presentation may be going over the heads of some users who would find the questions both interesting and answerable.

*Possible suggestion:* spend some more time trying to answer questions; attempt to write lengthy and complete answers to basic questions. In the processes you may uncover some weak spots in your own understanding of the basics. Then (search the site and if you don't find answers) ask after those weaknesses in particular. There tend to be patterns in the blind-spots and misunderstandings that people develop as they go along and asking a carefully crafted question about one of those will resonate with both teachers and students.